Finding all words of length n+1 by adding one extra letter from words of length n
I have several long list consisting of thousand of words sorted by length, one list for every word length. For every word of length n in a list I would like to generate all words from the list with words of length n+1, that is just by adding one extra letter. The word 'EXAMPLE' should hence generate 'EXAMPLED, EXAMPLES, EXEMPLAR, MEGAPLEX', presuming these words are in the list with eight letter words.
By trial and error I have found something that does the job but it is messy and runs for ages as I am very new to Python. I struggled a lot with all the variations with duplicate letters... As I want to extend this to cover all word lenghts, what is a better and more efficient way to get the the job done?
    SevenPlusOneList = []
    for word7 in ListOfSevens:
        SevenPlusOne = []
        SevenCount = collections.Counter(word7)
            for word8 in ListOfEights:
            EightCount = collections.Counter(word8)
            NotSharedLetters = {k: SevenCount[k] for k in EightCount if k in EightCount and SevenCount[k] != EightCount[k]}
            if len(NotSharedLetters) == 1 and len(EightCount) >= len(SevenCount) and (len(EightCount)-len(SevenCount) == 1 or list(NotSharedLetters)[0] in SevenCount):
                SevenPlusOne.append(word8)
            if len(SevenPlusOne) > 0:
                SevenPlusOneList.append(SevenPlusOne)
            else:
                SevenPlusOneList.append('-')


please correct your indentation. could you define valid word, as it is not clear by reading your code?

I think this question may be answered better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com .

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@charmoniumQ probably not: the program must be complete, its purpose well defined and the asker must clearly state they want a review. optimization questions are ok for stack overflow

Let's say your starting point is a list of 7-letter words in no particular order. For your 8-letter words, build a dictionary where the key is a tuple representing the word in its sorted order.
For example:
{
    ('a', 'i', 'l', 'o', 'r', 's', 't'): ["solitary", "royalist"]
}

You can then iterate over your list, add a letter, sort the result then inspect the dictionary to [try to] find a match.
Here's a working example.
My wordlist.txt file contains 96,511 words (all lowercase) of which 32,654 are 7-letter words and 26,566 are 8-letter words.
This code generates 89,597 lines of output in less than 0.5s (including construction of the list and dictionary).
from pathlib import Path
from string import ascii_lowercase
from collections import defaultdict

def main():
    w7 = set()  # set of 7-letter words
    w8 = defaultdict(set)  # dictionary of 8-letter words keyed on the sorted word (as a tuple)
    with Path("~/wordlist.txt").expanduser().open() as words:
        for word in map(str.strip, words):
            match len(word):
                case 7:
                    w7.add(word)
                case 8:
                    k = tuple(sorted(word))
                    w8[k].add(word)
                case _:
                    pass
    with Path("~/result.txt").expanduser().open("w") as output:
        for word in w7:
            for c in ascii_lowercase:
                if (w := w8.get(tuple(sorted(word + c)))) is not None:
                    print(f"{word} ->", *w, file=output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Platform:
macOS 15.0.1
Apple M2
Python 3.13.0

Timing examples:
time python Oct28.py
python3 Oct28.py  0.38s user 0.02s system 95% cpu 0.412 total


Very nice.  But I don't think it's totally correct.  I can't come up with an 8-letter example, but "loop" and "pool" would have the same dictionary key.  When you build your w8 dictionary only one of those two words could appear.

@PaulCornelius You are quite right. I have amended the code accordingly

This solution runs in less than a second on a dict of 25143 total words. It avoids doing a double loop over 7 and 8 length words because it uses a defaultdict to hold the 8 length words instead. (The only issue is how to handle capital letters. I lowercased the words before comparing them)
from collections import defaultdict
from string import ascii_lowercase

seven = [] # all seven letter words in the dictionary 'usr/dict/words'
eight = defaultdict(list)
same = defaultdict(list)
eight_count = 0 # number of eight letter words in the dictionary 'usr/dict/words'
total_words = 0 # total words in the dictionary 'usr/dict/words'

with open('/old_data/usr/dict/words', 'r') as f:
    for word in f:
        total_words += 1
        word = word.strip()
        if len(word) == 7:
            seven.append(word)
        elif len(word) == 8:
            eight_count += 1
            sort = ''.join(sorted(word.lower()))
            eight[sort].append(word)

for word_7 in seven:
    for letter in ascii_lowercase:
        sort = ''.join(sorted(word_7.lower()+letter))
        if sort in eight:
            same[word_7].extend(eight[sort])

with open('letters.txt', 'w') as f:
    for word, array in same.items():
        print(word, array, file = f)

    print('seven letter words in usr/dict/words ', len(seven), file=f) #4072
    print('eight letter words in usr/dict/words ', eight_count,file=f) #3621
    print('total words in usr/dict/words ', total_words,file=f) #25143
    print('len(eight) dict ', len(eight),file=f) #3547

It produces output like:
abdomen ['doberman']
Abraham ['Alhambra']
abreact ['bacteria', 'crabmeat']
abstain ['absentia']
account ['occupant']
acetate ['catenate']
acetone ['anecdote']
acronym ['monarchy', 'acrimony', 'normalcy']
actinic ['cationic']
actress ['Socrates']
Addison ['Davidson']
adenine ['Adrienne', 'andesine']
admiral ['madrigal']
adrenal ['calendar', 'alderman']
advisee ['adhesive']
advisor ['advisory']
against ['Santiago']
agitate ['tailgate']
aileron ['Caroline', 'Cornelia', 'regional', 'Lorraine', 'oriental']
airdrop ['raindrop']
airfare ['airframe']
airline ['bilinear', 'inertial']
airmail ['familiar']
airport ['Pretoria', 'Fairport', 'portrait']
....
wattage ['megawatt']
wearied ['areawide']
weather ['whatever']
Webster ['Brewster']
welfare ['farewell']
Wharton ['hawthorn']
whether ['herewith']
whither ['herewith']
Whitman ['Wightman']
whoever ['whomever']
wigging ['swigging', 'twigging']
Wiggins ['swigging']
Wilfred ['wildfire']
William ['Williams']
wolfish ['blowfish']
Woodard ['hardwood', 'Woodward', 'woodward', 'woodyard']
Woodrow ['woodwork']
woodrow ['woodwork']
workday ['workaday']
wrangle ['Walgreen']
wreathe ['whatever']
wrestle ['westerly']
seven letter words in usr/dict/words  4072
eight letter words in usr/dict/words  3621
total words in usr/dict/words  25143
len(eight) dict  3547


This program has the same time complexity as yours, so it may be faster or slower. The time complexity is: O(m×n).
It uses a Python module called PyDictionary, and whenever it can't find a meaning for a specific word, it will return None.
Here is my program I wrote:
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary # A dictionary for Python that can find meanings (and validate words)

dictionary: PyDictionary = PyDictionary() # Create a new class object "dictionary"

word7: list[str] = ["questin"] # Just an example
alphabet: list[str] = [
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",
    "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n",
    "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u",
    "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
]

valid_words: list[str] = []

for word in word7:
    for index, _character in enumerate(word): # Used prefix underscore because _character isn't used
        for letter in alphabet:
            try:
                new_word = word[0:index + 1] + letter + word[index+1:len(word)]
                if dictionary.meaning(new_word): # If a meaning is found for a word, then proceed
                    valid_words.append(new_word)
            except Exception as e: # If it gets an Exception, that most likely means that the word doesn't exist
                pass # Skip

print(valid_words)

